# Use select() instead of foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to simplify this code using linq select

I would like to remove few items from my list and add new items to list with same index. This below code works..I am checking if this can be simplified with LINQ select statement instead of foreach.

```
if (newHits.Any())
{
    int newHitIndex = 0;
    foreach (var h in allHits.ToList())
    {
        if (h.Type == type)
        {
            var index = allHits.FindIndex(a => a.Hit == h.Hit);
            var newHit = newHits[newHitIndex];
            allHits.RemoveAt(index);
            allHits.Insert(index, newHit);
            newHitIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Linq's `Select` is used for *selecting* and possibly performing an operation on member of a collection. It's not supposed to be used to delete and re-add items in the collection. In my opinion Linq wouldn't be the best way to do a task like this and i don't think that's what it's supposed to be used for.

Comment: There is a way to do some of this with LINQ, but it will probably not end up being as clean as you want. That being said, there are definitely other ways to make this code cleaner. What types are `newHits` and `allHits`?

Comment: Is Hit a unique key?  Is `var index = allHits.FindIndex(a => a.Hit == h.Hit);` trying to find the index of h?

Comment: You can remove the `if` by filtering the list to begin with: `foreach (var h in allHits.Where(hit => hit.Type == type))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the same code but simplified slightly by selecting the indexes first, and then filtering on items where the `Type` is the one we care about. We've also removed the `if (newHits.Any())`, since that isn't really a safeguard against us selecting more items from `allHits` than `newHits` contains (in the original code we were blindly incrementing and using `newHitIndex` without checking the bounds of `newHits`).

See if this works for you:

```
int newHitIndex = 0;

foreach (var index in allHits.Select((item, index) => index)  // Select the index
    .Where(i => allHits[i].Type == type))                     // Filter on Type
{
    if (newHitIndex == newHits.Count) break;   // Stop when we get to the end of newHits
    allHits[index] = newHits[newHitIndex++];   // Set value and increment in one line
}
```

---

Another way to do this would be to select the indexes of the `allHits` items we want to change into a `List<int>`, get the smaller of that `Count` and `newHits.Count`, and then in a `for` loop do our assignments:

```
var allHitsIndexes = allHits.Select((item, index) => index)
    .Where(i => allHits[i].Type == type).ToList();

var maxCount = Math.Min(newHits.Count, allHitsIndexes.Count);

for (var i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
{
    allHits[allHitsIndexes[i]] = newHits[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (newHits.Any())
{
    int newHitIndex = 0;
    var allHitsList = allHists.ToList();
    for(var index =0; index < allHitsList.Count; ++index)
    {
        var h = allHitsList[index]
        if (h.Type == type)
        {
            var newHit = newHits[newHitIndex];
            allHitsList[index] = newHit;
            newHitIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

then convert `allHitsList` to whatever type `allHits` is.

Comment: You could simplify this further by changing line 4 to `var allHitsList = allHits.Where(h => h.Type == type).ToList();` which will enable you to remove the `if` check.

Comment: @Abion47: then we'd be working with a partial list instead of the full list.  We need the full list with the `type` objects at their correct index.

Comment: As it's written, you are doing all the processing and replacements on `allHitsList` which doesn't affect `allHits` (unless `allHits` is itself a `List`, in which case the `ToList()` and subsequent assignment is redundant anyway). The only thing you're currently using `index` for is getting/setting the value in the generated list at that `index`, which doesn't really matter whether it's the full or partial list.

Comment: @Abion47, correct, this is why I added the line at the end about converting `AllHitsList` to `AllHits` -- since I didn't know what type `AllHits` was.  But the point is, AllHitsList is an exact replica of what AllHits should look like.  Your way, could be reduced to just `newHits.ToList()` -- But we need to replace speicif spots in AllHits.